# Ubuntu Freezes After Suspend Mode

Tags: 16.04, suspend, gnome-terminal, xfce, ubuntu-gnome

Problem: I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS a few months ago until recently I installed XFCE on Ubuntu. Then all the problems started. Whenever I put my system in Suspend mode, and then come back turn it to work it is not possible. I cannot click on anything, no folder or program gets opened. Later I uninstalled XFCE and purged using terminal, but GNOME Ubuntu has still problems.

Question 1: Is there any way I can fix this from Ubuntu terminal command line ?

Question 2: Would uninstalling Ubuntu and rebooting it back fix the problem ?

Question 3: Is there any other good and easy way to fix this problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: It helps to know the make and model of your computer, CPU and GPU.

Comment: I am still looking forward to an answer if someone knows a way to fix this problem please let me know.